# Jenkinsfile build log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any builtin variable that gives access to the text of the currently executing build?

I tried using something like `currentBuild.log`, `currentBuild.buildLog` but without any luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually it is possible using `currentBuild.rawBuild.log` or better (not deprecated) `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(100)` (for the last 100 lines), reference: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getLog-int-

Comment: With 1.652 multibranch pipeline, that doesn't work :( `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getLog int` & the my.jenkins.site/scriptApproval/ page doesn't even show it.  I'm still looking for an answer myself to this vexing problem

Comment: @JasonDeArte - Have you tried this on the current Jenkins LTS with current  plugin versions?

Comment: Took me a long time to find this answer. This provides one way to tell if a build was aborted, which isn't clearly provided yet - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28822

Comment: How can I use get ALL the logs of the current build? currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(100) works but currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog() is not working (empty) while I was hoping for all the logs.

Answer (score 11):

I searched a lot for a solution to analyze the log.

- use `rawBuild` was not OK, because I want to execute my scripts in a sandbox without additional approvals
- use `tee` in the steps, that I want to analyse was not OK, because I don't want to modify previous steps, nor I don't want to have my whole log in RAM (and unfortunately I needed that on a Windows machine)

I found a solution inspired by Jesse Glicks answer:

- Under my.jenkins.url/pipeline-syntax/globals you can see, that the `manager`-variable allows you to analyse the log by using `manager.logContains(regexp)` or `manager.getLogMatcher(regexp)`
- So if you just want to check, that your log contains string `myTestString` you can just call `manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*')`
- If you want to get some information from the first matching line you can use `manager.getLogMatcher(regexp)`

Unfortunately I found no way to analyze the whole log (`getLogMatcher` returns only the first matching line Matcher). So I see currently no way to e.g. count how often a log file contains a special string.

Comment: there is no more "manager" in jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals as for august 2018. But there is "currentBuild" that has rawBuild property that has getLog(int).

Answer (score 4):

Not currently. (Properties of `currentBuild` are documented under *Snippet Generator » Global Variables* by the way.)

It *could* be implemented, fairly easily, though it would not scale well with huge builds. [JENKINS-28119](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28119) would provide a more scalable solution to what I am guessing your underlying request is.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to parse the logs to retrieve all deployed artifacts (`mvn clean deploy`) and in case the server tests fail I want to remove those artifacts from nexus repository, the easiest way currently for me is to parse the logs for *Uploaded: http.....* text and do HTTP DELETE on them.

Comment: If you are versioning your deployed artifacts with some variable which you can access, like your build number or your git commit, you can maybe delete them by building the artifact names using the variable. If you are publishing hundreds of artifacts that won't work too well though

Comment: Then just `sh 'mvn clean deploy | tee logs'; def logs = readFile 'logs'` without trying to access the logs of the _build_ as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins gives you `BUILD_URL`, you can download it:

```
sh('wget -q --no-check-certificate -O build.log ' + BUILD_URL + 'consoleText')
```

Comment: Note that this only work when anonymous read access to jenkins builds is allowed. But that might be better than using `currentBuild.rawBuild.log` and allow access to `rawBuild` for scripts.