# Get all logs of the current Jenkins build with currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want all my jenkins logs of my current build in groovy

```
env.logs = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(1000).join('\n')
```

This works, but the problem here is I have to specify the amount of lines.
When I use:

```
env.logs = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog().join('\n')
```

`env.logs` is empty. What is the right command to get all the logs without specifying the amount of lines. Is this possible?

currentBuild.rawBuild.log seems to work but is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018509/jenkinsfile-build-log)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getLog method with a max value `getLog(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: seems not to work for me? It remains empty. Do I have to import a specific class? On what is the integer.MAX_VALUE based?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me - it reads the actual log file instead of using the API:

```
logFileContent = new File("${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log").collect {it}
```